# Simple Dropdown with arrows in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a simple dropdown with product listings which will filter the products on click, so the dropdown is **Onclick**.

Issue -

I have multiple products in a category, i'm trying to have a dropdown which will collapse other products which are not used on click.

The current script i have collapses everything and opens it up again and not able to attach a class to it to show downarrow when opened.

It is way too buggy is there any other way to achieve this or a tutorial / script or something.

Here is the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aUkku/71/).

```
$('.topnav li a').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().children().is('ul'))
    {
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
    }
    else
    {
        if($(this).parent().parent().is('ul.topnav'))
        {
            $('.topnav').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.topnav').find('ul').slideUp();
            $(this).parent().parent().slideDown('slow');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do??

Answer (score 0):

i dont have specific solution for your problem,

but still you can take a look at this `Select2` jquery plugin, you can have many facilities like searching and displaying image, just check this link  [Select2 - DropDown](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

please look below link

http://www.script-tutorials.com/click-action-multilevel-css3-dropdown-menu/

You can check demo over there for multilevel dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Changed a little bit of code(html and script) from your jsfiddle see if that is what you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/nextg_tech/4N3wA/

script

```
$('.topnav li a').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().children().is('ul'))
    {
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
    }
    else
    {
        if($(this).parent().parent().is('ul.topnav'))
        {
            $('.topnav').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.topnav').find('ul').slideUp();
            $(this).parent().parent().slideDown('slow');
        }
    }
});
```

html

```
<div class="container">
 <ul class="productfilters topnav">

    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All</a></li>
     <li class="hasarrow">
      <a href="#" id="nfbt" data-filter=".pone">Product 1</a>
        <ul class="ddone">
         <li class="hasarrow"><a href="#" data-filter=".ptwo">Sub Product 1</a>
                <ul class="ddone">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2 Product 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2 Product 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2 Product 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2 Product 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         <li><a href="#" data-filter=".pthree">Sub Product 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-filter=".pfour">Sub Product 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="hasarrow"><a href="#" data-filter=".pval">Product 2</a> 
     <ul class="ddone">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Product of 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Product of 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Product of 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Product of 2</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```